# Branch.io - How to have one quick link that takes dynamic parameters?

Tags: deep-linking, branch.io

My app has many promos (dynamically created from a CMS)

I want to create a quick link that routes to mywebsite.app.link/promo and receives a promo ID in the data.

In my app I can then fetch the ID and route accordingly.

How can I achieve this in Branch.io?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Simply load the SDK in your CMS (or wherever you are using it). You'll want to do something like the following:

```
(function(b,r,a,n,c,h,_,s,d,k){if(!b[n]||!b[n]._q){for(;s<_.length;)c(h,_[s++]);d=r.createElement(a);d.async=1;d.src="https://cdn.branch.io/branch-latest.min.js";k=r.getElementsByTagName(a)[0];k.parentNode.insertBefore(d,k);b[n]=h}})(window,document,"script","branch",function(b,r){b[r]=function(){b._q.push([r,arguments])}},{_q:[],_v:1},"addListener applyCode autoAppIndex banner closeBanner closeJourney creditHistory credits data deepview deepviewCta first getCode init link logout redeem referrals removeListener sendSMS setBranchViewData setIdentity track validateCode trackCommerceEvent logEvent disableTracking getBrowserFingerprintId".split(" "), 0);
      branch.init('YOURKEY', function(err, data) {
        var linkData = {
          campaign: '',
          channel: '',
          feature: '',
          stage: '',
          tags: [],
          alias: '',
          data: {
            'myCustomData': '1',
            'myOtherCustomData': '2'
          }
        };
        branch.link(linkData, function(err, link) {
          console.log(link); //This is link you use
        });
      }
    );
```

Then when Branch initialises on your device, the data fields will be accessible, you don't need to setup any quick links in the Branch dashboard or anything like that

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for reaching out!

I am happy that you found an answer. There are multiple ways to add dynamic parameters to your links. Please find them linked below:

https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/creating-links/other-ways/ios/#appending-query-parameters

It is also possible to create a Branch link from scratch by just appending query params. Here is a quick table that shows you how you can go about doing this based on the domain that is configured for your Branch links:
https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/creating-links/other-ways/ios/#url-formats-by-base-domain-type

Please do let reach out to support@branch.io should you have any further questions!

Cheers,

Joie

Comment: Thanks Joie, very helpful stuff, I'm sure others will benefit too!